# QuickBooks NOT working on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I was trying to connect to quickbooks online from google app engine by just running this simple code:

```
OAuthCredentials oauthcredentials = new OAuthCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

PlatformSessionContext context = new PlatformSessionContext(oauthcredentials, appToken, PlatformServiceType.QBO, realmID);

QBCustomerService customerService = QBServiceFactory.getService(context, QBCustomerService.class);

QBIdType idType = new QBIdType(context);

idType.setValue("2");

QBCustomer c = customerService.findById(context, idType);

System.err.println(c.getName());
```

and it always throws me this error:

```
com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSException: java.net.SocketException: Operation failure: Unknown error.
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:118)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:82)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.setSocketOptionAsBytes(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketOptions$BooleanCheckFunction.apply(AppEngineSocketOptions.java:168)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketOptions$Option.validateAndApply(AppEngineSocketOptions.java:358)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketOptions$Option.validateAndApply(AppEngineSocketOptions.java:373)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.setOption(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:144)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.setOption(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:171)
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:950)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.setTcpNoDelay(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.prepareSocket(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSRestClient.sendRequest(IDSRestClient.java:557)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSRestClient.get(IDSRestClient.java:160)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.QBOService.getQBOBaseURI(QBOService.java:24)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSRestClient.setServiceTypeProperty(IDSRestClient.java:698)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.QBORequestCreator.doIDSGet(QBORequestCreator.java:41)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.AbstractQBOBaseDataService.findById(AbstractQBOBaseDataService.java:185)
    at com.intuit.ds.qb.qbo.QBOCustomerService.findById(QBOCustomerService.java:153)
    at com.xyz.server.tasks.SyncCustomerTask.runMethod(SyncCustomerTask.java:85)
    at com.xyz.server.tasks.SyncCustomerTask.run(SyncCustomerTask.java:33)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DeferredTaskServlet.performRequest(DeferredTaskServlet.java:136)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DeferredTaskServlet.service(DeferredTaskServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

where at `com.xyz.server.tasks.SyncCustomerTask.runMethod(SyncCustomerTask.java:85)` is the `findbyId("2")` line in my code.
Any suggestions how to get around this issue?
Any help will be really really appriciated

Comment: Are you able to make REST APIs calls from Google App Engine to Intuit? According to the google docs, outbound sockets are for paid apps and not available on development apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppEngine provides only a limited [Socket API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/overview). In particular, you cannot use most `getsockopt`/`setsockopt` calls, which in your case throw the error (`setTcpNoDelay(..)`).

QuickBooks SDK seems to be closed-source, so there is no way around it.

**Update:**

As of [GAE Java SDK 1.8.1](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes)., it's possible to use socket options methods: they are a no-op, but they do not throw exceptions as they used to:

`The Sockets API now allows client code to call get/set options against sockets. Previously, calls raised "Not Implemented" exceptions. When java.net.Socket.get<option>() is called, a mock value is returned, calls to set<option>() will be silently ignored.`

Answer (score 0):

I am SO thankful that you posted this question.  I had been banging my head against the wall for days with the same problem, except I am developing my Google App in the Go language, not Java.  BUT I MADE IT WORK!  I hope that my solution will help you also.  Basically, instead of using the sockets service, I am using the URL Fetch service, documented for Java here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

I am pretty clueless about some of the details in your original post (I have not developed in Java, and am not familiar with the QBServiceFactory nor the OAuthCredentials).  So I am not sure how much control you have over how it actually sends the requests to QB.  But worst case scenario, I think you may be able to write your own functions to replace the QBServiceFactory (which I have had to do in Go), and if you make sure they use the URL Fetch service instead of sockets, you may have better luck.

As I said, I am very thankful for your question, because I do not think that I would have stumbled across my answer otherwise, so thank you!