# Request for Request Token from Intuit IPP gives permission denied

Tags: google-app-engine, go, intuit-partner-platform

I am doing this on my local development site without problems.  But when I try to setup a new connection to a QuickBooks file from my live site, I get a permission denied error.

Here is the error returned: "Post https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token: permission denied"

Here are the request headers

```
Content-Type
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Authorization
  OAuth oauth_consumer_key="MY_KEY",
  oauth_nonce="MY_NONCE",
  oauth_signature="MY_SIG",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="1377287041",
  oauth_version="1.0"
```

Here is the request body:

```
oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.intheloop-notes.com%2Fqb%2Fconnect%2Freturn%2F
```

---- EDIT ----

The response is nil altogether, I am getting an error from my Go code on:

```
response, err := client.Do(request)
```

Which is why I have added a couple of tags to this question (go and google-app-engine) to try and broaden my audience.  I am pretty sure that the error is in the way that my OAuth library is sending the request.  I am using this library: https://github.com/kurrik/oauth1a, which has been working just fine on my local development site, but gives me the "permission denied" error when I make the call from my live site.  I think there is some difference in the way that the development app engine server creates the request from the way the live engine does, but I am not sure exactly what.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try this using ApiExplorer.
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

Comment: Yes, Manas, you should know I can as you have helped me out with a few other questions regarding my project ;)

Comment: I can easily connect using the API Explorer (even using the exact same tokens/secrets), and like I said, my local dev app is connecting just fine.  I feel like it may be a setting with my IPP account, or a header that I am sending (or not sending)...

Comment: Yes Blair. But without looking at your code, it is hard to tell what exactly is happening. You can use some tools like Fiddler(or any other http snooper) to see what Http URL and header r getting passed from ur app. You can compare the same with that of ApiExplorer. That might help.

Comment: Hi Manas, I tried to use Fiddle (a neat little program, thanks for turning me on to that) but it doesn't capture the request made to https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token, I think because that request is initiated by my Go code from the server, not from my local machine.  The best I can give you is what I already have in my original question, which is what my Go code reports as the headers for both the request and the response.

Comment: Hi again Manas, see my edits to the original question, I think that maybe this is a Google Go / appengine issue more than an ipp question

Comment: Hi Blair, I should have guessed that u r using GAE with Go.
In GAE, there are some limitations on low level sockets. Please refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400557/quickbooks-not-working-on-google-app-engine. I've not tested it using GAE. So, at present I don't have any concrete ans. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm very excited by that response, but thank you for pointing me to that question.  I hope I can figure out a way around this, or else I've wasted 4 months of development.

Comment: Eureka! I figured it out!  And thank you, Manas, I would not have found this solution without that last link you gave.  For anyone who is wondering: I had to create a custom http.Client using the appengine.urlfetch library.  Once I figured that out, the solution was simple, I just had to change one line of code that created the client into this: client := urlfetch.Client(appengine.NewContext(r)).  Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka! I figured it out! And thank you, Manas, I would not have found this solution without that last link you gave. For anyone who is wondering: I had to create a custom http.Client using the appengine.urlfetch library. Once I figured that out, the solution was simple, I just had to change one line of code that created the client into this:

```
client := urlfetch.Client(appengine.NewContext(r))
```

Problem solved!