# AppEngine: Could not verify SSL certificate for URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am attempting to connect to Intuit Quickbooks with OAuth, using their JAVA API V3, hosted on AppEngine (SDK 1.8.4). To get started, I'm just running their sample code from their instructions here: http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_QuickBooksAPI/0055_DevKits/0201_IPP_Java_DevKit_3.0

It's working well on TomCat, but when I adapt the code to work on AppEngine, I get this error:

#### OauthHelper.java Extract, the exception is raised at the last line:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import oauth.signpost.http.HttpParameters;

[...]
URL url;
url = new URL(signedRequestTokenUrl);
HttpURLConnection httpconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
httpconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/xml");
httpconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
if (httpconnection != null) {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpconnection.getInputStream()));
[...]
```

#### Causing this Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for URL: https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_signature=VzStL8UcIoDrgKdcU7jJAWaux5Y%3D&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Faccesstoken.htm&oauth_consumer_key=qyprdulFn7zfTw5ewpZhkPxSo4q27X&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1379761817&oauth_nonce=5706619579888946790
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:144)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
at com.intuit.utils.OauthHelper.getRequestTokenSignPost(OauthHelper.java:167)
```

#### The url is as follows:

```
https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?oauth_signature=xxxx&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Faccesstoken.htm&oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1379768671&oauth_nonce=-78989043
```

The exact same piece of code works perfectly on TomCat 7.

#### Signpost

I also tried to replace DefaultOAuthConsumer & DefaultOAuthProvider by the following:

```
oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
```

, but it generates exactly the same exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can refer these two links - Hope it will be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410948/request-for-request-token-from-intuit-ipp-gives-permission-denied

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400557/quickbooks-not-working-on-google-app-engine

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, see this app engine issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5203. Please star this issue to get it some more attention, I also believe this is a regression as there are earlier closed issues with this same bug.

Answer (score 2):

And right after I say that I tried something that to me makes little sense, but seems to work, try this:

```
        URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
        FetchOptions lFetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.validateCertificate();
        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, lFetchOptions);
        HTTPResponse response = fetcher.fetch(request);
```

For me it was the FetchOptions.Builder and explicitly setting "validateCertificate()"; See if this solve it for you.